# Can we use specific time when using past simple with past perfect?

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, simple-past

I wonder if it's possible and correct to put a specific time like this.

> I had finished my homework **at 6 am.** before I went to school **at 7 am**.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence doesn't sound idiomatic. If you are so keen on expressing the times of your actions, you could say:

> I finished my homework at 6 am ***AND*** I went to school at 7 am.

as 6 am is obviously ***before*** 7 am.

If you want to concentrate on ***before*** then maybe 7am can be omitted:

> I had finished my homework at 6 am., before I went to school.

You could also omit 6am, depending on what you want to stress:

> I had finished my homework before I went to school at 7 am.